# java.sql.SQLException: Could not commit with auto-commit set on at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:4443)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I just upgrade to new jdbc driver from classes12.jar to ojdbc7.jar

My app threw an exception when was running with ojdbc7.jar:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not commit with auto-commit set on
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:4443)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:4490)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doSetAutoCommit(T4CConnection.java:943)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.setAutoCommit(PhysicalConnection.java:4
```

My app still run normally with classes12.jar.

I researched on oracle:

This exception is raised for any one of the following cases:

- When auto-commit status is set to true and commit or rollback method is called
- When the default status of auto-commit is not changed and commit or rollback method is called
- When the value of the COMMIT_ON_ACCEPT_CHANGES property is true and commit or rollback method is called after calling the acceptChanges method on a rowset

But i couldn't find mistake in my source. Please help me give more explaination about this error.

Comment: Try setting `connection.setAutoCommit(false);`

Comment: Make sure you're using JDK7: that's what the "7" means in "ojdbc7".  The classes12.jar is JDK 1.2 vintage - you should have changed years ago.  Don't be fooled by "my app still runs normally with classes12.jar".  You should not use that ever again.

Comment: Given the callstack I'd suspect a bug in the driver. When switching between autocommit `true` and `false` (and vice versa), the driver must commit the active transaction, and it looks like this commit fails because the driver is in autocommit. On the other hand, I'd expect Oracle to thoroughly test their driver for these kind of basic state switches.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Please look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272317/java-sql-sqlexception-could-not-commit-with-auto-commit-set-on I think my question is related to this thread

Answer (score 27):

The latest OJDBC drivers are more compliant then they where.   You can turn off this behavior for legacy code:

```
-Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false
```

It's a JVM option.

Answer (score 14):

This kind of exceptions occur when the Oracle JDBC Driver (ojdbc6.jar) version 12 or above will be used. Version 12 and above of the driver is more strictly than earlier driver versions.

You can solve the problem, you have few options:

1. Change jar file to old version.( Below 12; usually issue occurs while migrating to new server)
2. Override behavior of new jar version(ojdbc6.jar) with setting below JVM arguments.

   -Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false

   IBM WAS users, refer [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21417365):
3. Set Auto Commit off in Java/SQL:

   Java:

   conn.setAutoCommit(false);

   Oracle:

   SET AUTOCOMMIT OFF

Answer (score 5):

## Root Cause -

PhysicalConnector.java in ojdbc6

```
public void commit(int paramInt) throws SQLException {
    disallowGlobalTxnMode(114);
    if (this.lifecycle != 1) {
        SQLException sQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 8);
        sQLException.fillInStackTrace();
        throw sQLException;
    }
    .
    .
```

PhysicalConnector.java in ojdbc7

```
public void commit(int paramInt) throws SQLException {
    disallowGlobalTxnMode(114);
    ​if (this.autoCommitSpecCompliant && getAutoCommit()) {
        throw (SQLException)DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 273).fillInStackTrace();
    }
    if (this.lifecycle != 1) {
        SQLException sQLException = DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 8);
        sQLException.fillInStackTrace();
        throw sQLException;
    ​}
    .
    .
```

We can see that in ojdbc7, there is some piece of code has been introduced. If `autoCommitSpecCompliant` and `getAutoCommit()` both are true, we will be getting exception.

## Two Fixes Available -

1. **set autoCommitSpecCompliant false**
   Below JVM parameter to be set
   `-Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false`
2. **insert below piece of code before `connection.commit()`**

`connection.setAutoCommit(false);`

Answer (score 0):

We are IBM WAS v9 with using ojbc6.jar Above configure applied to APP Server, Node agent and DMGR, then it works.

`-Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false`

Dmgr: 
Deployment manager > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine 
Modify "Generic JVM arguments"

NodeAgent: 
Node agents > nodeagent > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine

WebSphere Application Server: 
Application servers > WebSphere_Portal > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine 
Modify "Generic JVM arguments"

Answer (score 0):

There's another solution that you can do from code:

System.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant", "false");

Answer (score -1):

Changing this in Hibernate properties worked for me

hibernate.connection.release_mode=auto

Comment: Nothing in the question suggests the OP was using Hibernate.