# Weblogic Failed to refresh JDBC Persistence Manager

Tags: ejb, persistence, weblogic-10.x, oracle12c

I am running weblogic portal 10.3

We recently upgraded our oracle from 11.2 to 12.1.0.2.0

The 11g database schema was dumped when Weblogic was running and then imported to the 12c DB.

But now I see a strange problem:

On startup in my managedServer1.log.yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm log file I see the following exception:

```
    ####<Sep 8, 2016 11:28:41 AM CEST> <Error> <DataSync> <devmaster.xxx.com> <managedServer1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-0002F70BB8045A5B8E84> <e54db9af27ea4009:1806ee21:157091f8869:-7ffd-0000000000000002> <1473326921799> <BEA-400610> <Error performing initial refresh of persistent store. DataSync is probably in an incomplete or corrupted state.com.bea.p13n.management.data.repository.PersistenceException: Failed to refresh JDBC Persistence Manager.
    at com.bea.p13n.management.data.repository.persistence.transactions.AbstractTx.sync(AbstractTx.java:67)
    at com.bea.p13n.management.data.repository.persistence.JdbcDataSource.refresh(JdbcDataSource.java:215)
    at com.bea.p13n.management.data.repository.persistence.JdbcPersistenceManager.refresh(JdbcPersistenceManager.java:113)
    at com.bea.p13n.management.data.repository.internal.AbstractDataRepository.<init>(AbstractDataRepository.java:164)
    at com.bea.p13n.management.data.repository.MasterDataRepository.<init>(MasterDataRepository.java:49)
    at com.bea.p13n.management.data.repository.DataRepositoryFactory.getMasterDataRepository(DataRepositoryFactory.java:441)
    at com.bea.p13n.property.internal.PropertySetManagerImpl.ejbCreate(PropertySetManagerImpl.java:274)
    at com.bea.p13n.property.internal.PropertySetManager_bjbwe8_Impl.ejbCreate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.pool.StatelessSessionPool.createBean(StatelessSessionPool.java:232)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.pool.StatelessSessionPool.getBean(StatelessSessionPool.java:132)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.StatelessManager.preInvoke(StatelessManager.java:148)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.preInvoke(BaseRemoteObject.java:229)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessRemoteObject.__WL_preInvoke(StatelessRemoteObject.java:41)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:24)
    at com.bea.p13n.property.internal.PropertySetManager_bjbwe8_EOImpl.getPropertySets(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.wsrp.consumer.management.ProducerManagerImpl.internalGetCustomUserProperties(ProducerManagerImpl.java:867)
    at com.bea.wsrp.consumer.management.ProducerManagerImpl.<init>(ProducerManagerImpl.java:116)
    at com.bea.wsrp.consumer.management.producer.ProducerManager$Factory.<clinit>(ProducerManager.java:663)
    at com.bea.wsrp.consumer.registry.DbProducerRegistryAdapter.sync(DbProducerRegistryAdapter.java:60)
    at com.bea.wsrp.consumer.registry.ProducerRegistry$AddOrUpdateProducerAction.run(ProducerRegistry.java:725)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at com.bea.wsrp.consumer.registry.ProducerRegistry.refreshProducers(ProducerRegistry.java:420)
    at com.bea.wsrp.consumer.registry.ProducerRegistry.loadRegistry(ProducerRegistry.java:286)
    at com.bea.wsrp.consumer.registry.ProducerRegistry.load(ProducerRegistry.java:196)
    at com.bea.wsrp.consumer.registry.ProducerRegistry.getInstance(ProducerRegistry.java:160)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.PortalServlet.startProducerRegistryFilePoller(PortalServlet.java:599)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.PortalServlet.reinitInternal(PortalServlet.java:313)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.PortalServlet.initInternal(PortalServlet.java:268)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.PortalServlet.access$200(PortalServlet.java:125)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.PortalServlet$ServletLifecycleListenerImpl.init(PortalServlet.java:2190)
    at com.bea.netuix.util.ServletLifecycleListener.initOrReinitInternal(ServletLifecycleListener.java:131)
    at com.bea.netuix.util.ServletLifecycleService.addServletLifecycleListener(ServletLifecycleService.java:252)
    at com.bea.netuix.util.ServletLifecycleService.addServletLifecycleListener(ServletLifecycleService.java:183)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.PortalServlet.init(PortalServlet.java:259)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.PortalServlet.init(PortalServlet.java:236)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1984)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1958)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1877)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3174)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1527)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:489)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:201)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:249)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:28)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:672)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:59)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:187)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:379)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:52)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:31)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:170)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:124)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:181)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:97)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
    Caused By: com.bea.p13n.management.data.repository.PersistenceException: Cannot commit: java.sql.SQLException: Could not commit with auto-commit set on
    at com.bea.p13n.management.data.repository.persistence.transactions.AbstractTx.doTransaction(AbstractTx.java:118)
    at com.bea.p13n.management.data.repository.persistence.transactions.AbstractTx.sync(AbstractTx.java:62)
    at com.bea.p13n.management.data.repository.persistence.JdbcDataSource.refresh(JdbcDataSource.java:215)
    at com.bea.p13n.management.data.repository.persistence.JdbcPersistenceManager.refresh(JdbcPersistenceManager.java:113)
    at com.bea.p13n.management.data.repository.internal.AbstractDataRepository.<init>(AbstractDataRepository.java:164)
    at com.bea.p13n.management.data.repository.MasterDataRepository.<init>(MasterDataRepository.java:49)
```

The result of this is that EJBs cause some NullPointerExceptions and my code fails. If I refresh the page enough times, the EJBs seem to be refreshed and start working fine.

But on restarts this problem shows up again.

I tried clearing out the WEBLOGICJMSSTATE table before start up, but there seems to be no effect.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with the new driver. I guess the clue was in the text

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not commit with auto-commit set on
```

I got rid of the error setting this JVM param:

```
-Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false
```

Thanks to the answer here: [java.sql.SQLException: Could not commit with auto-commit set on at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:4443)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953534/java-sql-sqlexception-could-not-commit-with-auto-commit-set-on-at-oracle-jdbc-d)