# Could not commit with auto-commit on

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hikaricp

I have a spring boot application that configures it to use multiple data sources (Oracle and Postgres) also use Hikari. When I run the application it up and run successfully but when I can one of the endpoints I got the "Could not commit with auto-commit on" error. I tried to set Hikari auto-commit to false but it didn't help to solve the problem. Do you have any experience to solve this issue>

Comment: Probably you must set something on the database driver itself (like a custom property). For Oracle you have some hints here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953534/java-sql-sqlexception-could-not-commit-with-auto-commit-set-on-at-oracle-jdbc-d. On postgres not sure how to do it.

Comment: @pringi you know in the first step my application works with Oracle database but when I added Postgres SQL on spring boot data sources as a multi-data source I got this error.  I think there is a config to disable auto-commit for these data sources on spring-boot property file.